# Soundcloud Limit on Play Requests

Tags: soundcloud

I'm new with SoundCloud API and want to verify something about the Rate Limit on Play Requests.

Is the /tracks/:id/stream limit of 15K per 24h is for playing videos via the [html5-widget](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget)? does this mean I cannot play more than 15K songs per day? or i'm missing something..

Answer (score 0):

> These limits are applied to developer applications using the
>   SoundCloud API, and have no impact on the SoundCloud embedded player.

[Soundcloud Backstage Blog](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/limits)

Comment: So its just when i want to fetch a song info from the API by some identifier, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be counted as an API request.

Comment: It's really small amount, YouTube allows up to 50m points that equals to millions of requests daily

Comment: Also, is this limits are effect SC API: "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"? (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)

Answer (score 0):

These API limits only apply when making API requests with your Client ID (JavaScript, Python, Ruby, or Objective-C SDKs).  Because the HTML 5 Widget does not require an API key, these limits do not apply to that player.